# verifying Divergence Theorem for cylinder with function whose divergence is 0

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

[image]

In a question I am doing, I first am asked to find the most general function of the form

$F = f(\rho)e_{\rho}$

such that the divergence is 0. Calculating the divergence directly, and using the more general expression below, I found that the most general case is when $f(\rho) = \frac{A}{\rho}$

[image]

However, when verifying I got confused by the following thought: consider applying the divergence theorem to the cylinder. For the surface integral, the top and the bottom of the cylinder of radius 1 yields an integral of 0, as their normal vector is in the $e_{z}$ direction which is perpendicular to $e_{\rho}$. However, for the sides of the cylinder I get:

$\int_{z=1}^{2}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\frac{A}{\rho}\rho {e_\rho \cdot e_\rho} d\theta dz =\int_{z=1}^{2}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\frac{A}{1} d\theta dz \neq 0$

I am probably being exceedingly stupid but thank you for taking a look anyway :)

Comment: It sure looks like the vector field is undefined (discontinuous) along the $z$-axis, so the theorem does not apply.

Comment: thank you - I remember now, that this implies the space is not simply connected. was my derivation of the most general form of the function such that its divergence is 0 wrong then? this was part of an exam question, so presumably the answer should not be a function where the divergence theorem does not apply

Comment: Simple connectivity is not relevant here. It's relevant to asking if a curl-free vector field must be a gradient. What was the precise exam question you are referring to?

Comment: I have added the exam question to my question. thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note now that in the exam question, the region is *outside* the cylinder and *inside* the surface $z=1/r^2$, so the $z$-axis is totally outside the region and the divergence theorem will apply.  The bounds on $z$ tell you that $1\le r\le 2$. The computation will be more involved to find the flux directly.

Comment: i had a look again today and it all worked out fine and fairly easily. many thanks for clearing up my confusion with the domains

Comment: i had a look again today and it all worked out fine and fairly easily. many thanks for clearing up my confusion with the domains